# Acessing the json data from firestore with angular

Tags: json, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access the data from the firestore database in angular.

**This is my component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore';



interface Mission {
  cliente: string;
  luogo: string;
  materiale: string;
  nCassoni: number;
  nota: string;
  operatore: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-check-mission',
  templateUrl: './check-mission.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./check-mission.component.css']
})
export class CheckMissionComponent{

  missionsCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Mission>;
  missions: any;


  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.missionsCol = this.db.collection('mission');
    this.missionsCol.valueChanges().subscribe((_missions: any) => {
      this.missions = _missions;
    console.log(this.missions);
  }


}
```

**This is my html:**

```
<ul *ngFor="let mission of missions | async">
    <li>
        {{ mission.cliente }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the firestore I have 6 documents under `mission` and infact in the html page I see six points, but except that everithing is blank!

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

--I've updated the code and now I can log the results in the console, but I can't see  the deata inside the html.
The console is giving me this error `nvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError ..`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.missionsCol.valueChanges().subscribe((_missions: any) => {
  this.missions = _missions;
})
```

A note this will tigger everytime something in the missions json is changed.

Comment: thankyou for your comment, I'm getting in the console `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]..`

Comment: Propably cause `missions: Observable<Mission[]>;` need to be `missions: any;`

Comment: I've updated the code above with your suggestions, can you tell me if I inserted something in the wrong spot? Because I've tried but I can't make it work